# WebDav (httpFolder behaviour, open as WebDav-folder) does not work anymore in IE11 - what workaround?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webdav, internet-explorer-11

Microsoft IE8 and IE9 used to offer functionality to start 
a WebDAV explorer on a Windows computer from within a WebPage:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

  <SCRIPT>
    function fnDavStart(oSpanObj, sPath) {
      oSpanObj.navigateFrame(sPath, "_blank");
   }
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<body>
<div ID=davDiv>
<SPAN ID=oWebDavHelper style="behavior:url('#default#httpFolder');" onclick = "fnDavStart this, 'https://webdav.myserver.com')">
  Click here for WebDAV folder
</SPAN>
</div>
```

Now the method navigateFrame() and/or the behaviour "httpFolder" seems to be gone in IE11.
How to get similar functionality in IE11?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe try to use `X-UA-Compatible` forcing IE11 using IE9 standarts.

Comment: That helped - forcing IE11 down to IE9 did the trick - thanks!

Comment: I will make a proper answer to keep the things right.

Answer (score 1):

You can force *IE* to render like *IE9* with this code in your meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

It will make all *IE* versions (even the ones not yet released) to render pages and javascrit like *IE9*.

Answer (score -2):

I havent used the behaviour approach before, but have you checked if the SharePoint OpenDocuments object still works?

```
<a href="#" onclick="new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1').EditDocument('http://x.com/mydoc.doc');">Open Now</a>
```

Here's some code with the js embedded in java.
https://github.com/miltonio/milton2/blob/master/milton-server-ce/src/main/java/io/milton/http/fs/FsDirectoryResource.java

Comment: This actually IS still working, but is NOT what i was asking for. OpenDocuments opens single documents. #default#httpFolder was used to open the FileExplorer showing a complete hierarchy of
files and folders

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry I'd forgot about that behaviours stuff opening folders. Havent seen it used much.